# How to stream a stream?

Tags: php, zend-framework, stream, amazon-s3

is it possible to stream a stream from Zend_Service_Amazon_S3 (http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.amazon.s3.html#zend.service.amazon.s3.streaming) to the browser?

I'm looking for something like readfile (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) but then instead of a file as input I'd like a stream.

Comment: yo dawg, I heard you want to stream a stream with your stream? Sorry couldn't help it! ;P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just copy it to `STDOUT`, which is "a write-only stream that allows you to write to the output buffer mechanism in the same way as print() and echo()" ([manual](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)).

```php
stream_copy_to_stream($response->getStream(), STDOUT);
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar solution is to use

```
fpassthru($response->getStream())
```

As the [PHP manual clearly states](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php), `STDOUT` is only there for CLI SAPI.  But even on the CLI it is unavailable in a context like this

```
php < script.php
```

In that case (like if you try to use `STDOUT` with `php-fpm`) you get following error with `stream_copy_to_stream()`:

```
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant STDOUT - assumed 'STDOUT' in $FILE on line $LINE
PHP Warning:  stream_copy_to_stream() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in $FILE on line $LINE
```

This problem vanishes as soon as you use `fpassthru()`

I did not test this on AWS, but I am pretty sure it works there, too.